# How to set filters/automatically put email into correct bundle?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I am using Google's new Inbox, as a long time (pre-beta) GMail user I'm used to setting up filters to make sure some emails go to the correct places, as google never categories them correctly.

This option seems to no longer exist in inbox, how do I make sure emails about jobs (from specific job related email addresses) go into my 'Jobs' bundle, and not into low priority?

I have 'moved' specific emails of this type into the jobs folder, but once another one comes through it ends up in low priority again. I'd normally setup a filter but I can't find that option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @Sathya stated, you can't edit what ends up in the predefined bundles, but it's possible with the ones you create yourself.

In the menu, almost at the bottom, just above *Settings* you have *Create new...*.
But I assume you've already created "Jobs", since it I don't have it predefined in my Inbox.

Then, still in the menu, hover the bundle you want to edit and press the cog that appears.

The bundle's settings appear.[image: settings]

Press *ADD* to define what messages should be sorted into the bundle.

[image]

Here you have some options to filter by.

You can read more at the support page:
https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067566

Answer (score 7):

There's no option to automatically move all mails from specific addresses to pre-existing bundles - you'll [train Google Inbox by moving them](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6050237?p=labels_web&hl=en-GB&rd=1) to the bundles.

You can, however [create your own custom label (much like Gmail filters)](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067566) and then have the [label bundled it into Inbox](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067566)

Comment: But 'Jobs's isn't a pre-existing bundle, is it?

Comment: Ugh. That's annoying, because I could train it in one click by saying, "send all the emails from LinkedIn to my backup address straight to the garbage!"

Comment: @WayneWerner that's exactly what I was trying to do! - Sadly it's still not a thing!.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best way to edit your filters in Google inbox is to use the Gmail button in inbox to open your filters in Gmail. Here is how I did that:

1. Open inbox in a browser (not on the mobile app)
2. Make sure the menu bar is open on the left (by pressing the three bars at the top left)
3. Click the Gmail button
4. From this page your can open the settings options using the gear on the top right
5. Click filters and blocked addresses

This will bring up all your older filters and the new inbox filters that put email into each category. You can even modify the filters that Google Inbox added.

[image]